# How can I increase the byte limit in my ASP.Net Core SOAP ServiceContract?

Tags: asp.net-core, soap

I have an ASP.Net Core 3 application that communicates with the Quickbooks Web Connector.

I am having trouble figuring out how to increase the max allowed bytes from 8192 to something larger. Most of the Quickbooks requests contain more data than this.

I have the following in my service contract:

QBWC.asmx

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = @"http://developer.intuit.com/")]
public interface IQBWCService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int receiveResponseXML(string ticket, string response, string hresult, string message);
}
```

and in my Startup.cs

```
app.UseSoapEndpoint<IQBWCService>("/qbwc/qbwc.asmx", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer, true);
```

When Quickbooks attempts to send anything larger than 8192 bytes, I get the following error:

`System.Xml.XmlException: The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.`

I can't find anything called MaxStringContentLength anywhere.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out.  Change this line

```
app.UseSoapEndpoint<IQBWCService>("/qbwc/qbwc.asmx", new BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer, true);
```

to this

```
var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 5000000;  
app.UseSoapEndpoint<IQBWCService>("/qbwc/qbwc.asmx", httpBinding, SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer, true);
```